# How to attach a new video and remove old one in Media Source Extensions(SourceBuffer)

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, media-source

I am trying to play multiple using different buttons but when I am adding new video on click of button how to add the video to current buffer and flush the old file video.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
           integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 200px">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="initVideo('box1.mp4')">Video1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="initVideo('box.mp4')">Video2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="initVideo(3)">video3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="initVideo(4)">video4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <video  poster="data:image/gif,AAAA"  controls width="400"height="300" ></video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    var assetURL = "box.mp4";
    // Need to be specific for Blink regarding codecs
    // ./mp4info frag_bunny.mp4 | grep Codec
    var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001f, mp4a.40.2"';
    var totalSegments = 1;
    var segmentLength = 0;
    var segmentDuration = 0;
    var bytesFetched = 0;
    var requestedSegments = [];
    var sourceBuffer = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalSegments; ++i) requestedSegments[i] = false;
    var mediaSource = null;
    if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
        mediaSource = new MediaSource;
        //console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // closed
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
    } else {
        console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
    }

    function initVideo(url) {
        video.remove();
        //video.play()
        assetURL = url;
        console.log(sourceBuffer);
        console.log();
        mediaSource.sourceBuffers[0].appendBuffer
        video.load();;
    }

    function sourceOpen(_) {
        sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        console.log(mediaSource.readyState);
        getFileLength(assetURL, function (fileLength) {
           // console.log((fileLength / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2), 'MB');
            //totalLength = fileLength;
            segmentLength = Math.round(fileLength / totalSegments);
            //console.log(totalLength, segmentLength);
            fetchRange(assetURL, 0, segmentLength, appendSegment);
            requestedSegments[0] = true;
            video.addEventListener('timeupdate', checkBuffer);
            video.addEventListener('canplay', function () {

                segmentDuration = video.duration / totalSegments;
                video.play();
                //console.log(mediaSource.readyState);
            });
            video.addEventListener('seeking', seek);
        });
    };

    function getFileLength(url, cb) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('head', url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            cb(xhr.getResponseHeader('content-length'));
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    ;

    function fetchRange(url, start, end, cb) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('get', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=' + start + '-' + end);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            //console.log('fetched bytes: ', start, end);
            bytesFetched += end - start + 1;
            cb(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    ;

    function appendSegment(chunk) {
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(chunk);
    }
    ;

    function checkBuffer(_) {
        var currentSegment = getCurrentSegment();
        if (currentSegment === totalSegments && haveAllSegments()) {
            console.log('last segment', mediaSource.readyState);
            mediaSource.endOfStream();
            video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', checkBuffer);
            mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceclose', sourceclose);
        } else if (shouldFetchNextSegment(currentSegment)) {
            requestedSegments[currentSegment] = true;
            console.log('time to fetch next chunk', video.currentTime);
            fetchRange(assetURL, bytesFetched, bytesFetched + segmentLength, appendSegment);
        }
        //console.log(video.currentTime, currentSegment, segmentDuration);
    }
    ;
    function sourceclose () {

    }
    function seek(e) {
        console.log(e);
        if (mediaSource.readyState === 'open') {
            sourceBuffer.abort();
            console.log(mediaSource.readyState);
        } else {
            console.log('seek but not open?');
            console.log(mediaSource.readyState);
        }
    }
    ;

    function getCurrentSegment() {
        return ((video.currentTime / segmentDuration) | 0) + 1;
    }
    ;

    function haveAllSegments() {
        return requestedSegments.every(function (val) {
            return !!val;
        });
    }
    ;

    function shouldFetchNextSegment(currentSegment) {
        return video.currentTime > segmentDuration * currentSegment * 0.8 && !requestedSegments[currentSegment];
    }
    ;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://github.com/kori002/mediaSource